# Connecting an HDMI monitor to a VGA laptop without losing resolution

Tags: display, resolution, hdmi, vga, hp-elitebook

I am trying to connect an [Hp EliteBook 840 G3](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/elite-products/elitebook-840.html) laptop to a 26'' TV monitor. The monitor has both HDMI and VGA inputs. When I connected the HDMI to an older laptop, I got a high resolution (about 1920x1080 or better). Strangely, the HP EliteBook does not have an HDMI output - only a VGA output (this is strange because it is a new laptop. I thought that VGA was an old standard that is not produced anymore). When I connect the monitor to the VGA output of the laptop, the largest resolution that I can get is 1360x768.

What can I do to get better resolution? Will it help if I buy an HDMI-to-VGA converter?

Comment: *"The monitor has both HDMI and VGA outputs."*  -- Monitors do not have output ports.  A monitor has input port(s). There could be a pass-through port.  The display signal originates from the laptop/PC.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks! I mixed up output with input. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notebook has what is called Display Port, you need a display port to hdmi cable to get full resolution output. HP part number 749288-001 or equvalent

Ports and connectors for the 840:

3 USB 3.0; 1 USB 3.0 charging; 1 DisplayPort 1.2; 1 VGA; 1 combo stereo headphone/mic jack; 1 AC power; 1 RJ-45; 1 side-docking connector.

Number 3 is Display Port

[image]

Your support page
http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?sp4ts.oid=7815294

Comment: You don't want a VGA to HDMI. You're starting with a lower resolution and then taking it to digital. It will work, but staying digital will give the best output.

Comment: I bought an HDMI-DisplayPort adapter, and indeed I am able to get 1920x1080 resolution. Thanks!

Comment: Number 2 (on the diagram) is DisplayPort, 3 is an SD card reader.